# Website / software for playing bridge against computer, but partnering with a human

Tags: bridge

There seems to be a lot of websites offering games against computer AND with a computer partner. There is also plenty of portals where you can play with 3 other people. I am looking for something in between - there is two of us and we want to practice by playing with computer opponents.
Anything that works in a browser, on a desktop (Linux / Windows only) or on an Android phone would be great.

It does not have to be free, but I would like to be able to get a free trial at least to be able to make sure it gives me what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this Android app, allowing all the things you list (and also duplicate hands for solo games!)

[WeWeWeb Bridge (free)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.weweweb.android.free.bridge&hl=en)

I seem to remember there's a way to access it in a web browser as well, but I haven't used that often.

Comment: thanks, I had looked at that but could not find the option to add two robots against two humans, but I may have overlooked that. Will have a look again.

Comment: I have indeed overlooked that, the feature is there.

Answer (score 3):

[Bridgebase Online](http://bridgebase.com) will do this. They call their computer players "robots". "Advanced" robots are $1/day, "Basic" ones are $1/week. The advanced ones are slower and stronger. I recall that they once offered free robot access one day per month, but it's not mentioned in the [FAQ](http://www.bridgebase.com/help/v2help/).

Comment: I only discovered this question after I posted mine. Anyway, the trick to playing 2 vs. robot is described in a forum post that Joe added to https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/51087/online-bridge-with-2-casual-players-vs-computer/51088#51088