# online bridge with 2 casual players vs computer?

Tags: bridge, online

I'd like to play bridge with a partner -- but against a computer so we can take as much time as we like. This option would be especially useful for beginners and people getting back into the game after years away.

Are there any options?

Funbridge apparently offered this in the past (and it's still mentioned on their website) ... but I just signed up and don't see it, nor did the person who posted https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/357741/how-to-play-two-player-practice-in-funbridge

BridgeBase.com (BBO) is mentioned on [Is there a good casual online place to practice/learn bridge?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3633/is-there-a-good-casual-online-place-to-practice-learn-bridge/3656#3656) but I don't see a 2-player mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bridge Base Online allows you to play against AI, just create a table with all robots and then replace N with your partner. See for example [this forum question](https://www.bridgebase.com/forums/topic/79636-playing-with-partner-against-others/).